# Вопрос про класс Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Не понимаю, что делает эта функция с классом Vue.
Подскажите ее предназначение.

```
Vue.filter("fileName", function(value) {
  let l = value.split("/");

  return l[l.length - 1];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это фильтр для vue, который разрезает строку на массив строк по разделителю "/" и возвращает последнее значение

В html пишем:
`1: {{ "some/path/to/file.txt" | fileName }} 2: {{ "Some/string/hello/world" | fileName }} 3: {{ "Some string hello world" | fileName }}`

Получаем
1: file.txt
2: hello
3: undefined

Функция split:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Vue фильтры:
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html